# Нахождение отрезка пересечения двух диапазонов дат

Tags: c#

Например, есть 2 временных отрезка:

- 12.11.2021 - 17.11.2021
- 10.11.2021 - 15.11.2021

У них пересечение это 12-е, 13-е, 14-е и 15-е числа, т.е. `N = 4`.

Как можно найти этот самый `N`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// предполагаю, что у вас есть два диапазона дат: [from1, to1] и [from2, to2]
// а также, что from1 <= to1 и from2 <= to2

var intersectionFrom = from1 > from2 ? from1 : from2; // начало пересечения
var intersectionTo   = to1 < to2 ? to1 : to2; // конец пересечения

if (intersectionFrom > intersectionTo)
{
    // не пересекаются
}
else
{
    // можно отнять даты и найти временной промежуток между ними
    var timeSpan = intersectionTo - intersectionFrom;
    // ну а ваше N это timeSpan.TotalDays + 1
}
```

Попробовать запустить код можно [тут](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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).

Comment: @aepot, чего удалили свой ответ?

Comment: у вас проще, я перемудрил, чисто алгоритмически